# Why is the value extracted from database not showing what is intended?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT StockChild.ProductId, Sum(StockChild.Qty) AS SumOfQty,
PRODUCTDETAILS.Title, Sum(SALESORDERchild.Stockout) AS SumOfStockout
FROM (PRODUCTDETAILS 
  INNER JOIN SALESORDERchild 
    ON PRODUCTDETAILS.productID = SALESORDERchild.ProductId) 
 INNER JOIN StockChild 
    ON PRODUCTDETAILS.productID = StockChild.ProductID
WHERE (((StockChild.ProductID)=[Forms]![StockChild]![ProductId]) 
  AND ((SALESORDERchild.ProductID)=[Forms]![StockChild]![ProductId]))

GROUP BY StockChild.ProductId, PRODUCTDETAILS.Title;
```

I'm trying to get the summation of values from 2 different tables using the above SQL Statement in access:
1) Sum of StockChild quantity based on productID
2) Sum of Salesorderchild Stockout based on productID

If i query it separately, i managed to get the values that i needed but i'm unable to put it into a single form.

but when i query it together as above, the values jump all over the place and i can't seem to understand why.

And if i add another record in the salesorderchild, of the already existing isbn, all the values will jump as well.

is there something that i am doing wrongly? or how should i go about to tackle this matter.

I added some explanations in the image attached.
[image]

Update:
I was trying another method whereby i just did a normal query for the initial stock to be displayed(which worked fine getting the numbers i need)

and over in the Total stockout i was trying out a

```
 =DSum("[stockout]","[SALESORDERchild]","[ProductId]=" & [Forms]!
  [StockChild]![ProductId])
```

but it was returning me a #Name? did i use this correctly?, should i do a vba code instead or is there a way to do it this way?

i tried the following vba code function as an alternative to select out the value but it was telling me the user-defined type not defined. am i missing out something? - (fixed this part by defining the reference of active x data object)

```
  Private Sub Form_Current()
     Dim intI As Integer
     Dim fld As Field


     Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
     Dim pid As String

     pid = ProductID.Value


     Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
     rst.Open "SELECT Sum(SALESORDERchild.Stockout) AS SumOfStockout FROM 
     SALESORDERchild WHERE SALESORDERchild.ProductID ='" & pid & "';", 
     CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

     tb_stockout.Value = rst.Fields("SumOfStockout")

 End Sub
```

Done Thanks everyone :)

Comment: You get what you ask for. You can't combine two group by questions like that.

Comment: Hey Jarlh, Don't understand why its showing me the value of 21 instead of 3 in the stockout table. is there something wrong with my sql statement? or is it not possible in this scenario that i'm trying to achieve

Comment: Join the tables as you do, but skip the GROUP BY part, and you'll see. (select those 4 columns.)

Comment: *every* row from Stock Child for a particular productid is being joined to *every* row from Stock Out for the same productid. So, if there are 7 rows in one table and 3 rows in the other, and you're summing a column from the latter table where each row's value is `1`, then you are still summing 7x3 instances of the value `1` - which by my reckoning comes out at 21.

Comment: Need to aggregate each table separately then join the aggregate queries to ProductDetails table. Or use domain aggregate functions in textbox ControlSource.

Comment: Hey thanks for the clarifications on that. I tried to do it separately as shown in the above update but still am facing some issues here and there. pardon me there is still alot of brushing up i have to do!

Comment: Resolves thanks alot guys i realised where the error was :) i forgot to remove the control source which i put in earlier.